# cannot go back to previous page after javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, html

```
if (buttonclicked()) {
    window.location.href = "Page2.html";
}
```

after the browser loads the page 2, I cannot go back to Index.html using the browser back button, everytime I click it, it redirects to Page2.html again

Comment: What is return your "buttonclicked()" function?

Comment: Make sure `buttonclicked()` doesn't always return `true` and it is wrapped in some event handler.

Comment: can you post your code go get the understanding

Comment: @Hanif it returns true if the button is clicked

Comment: @marvinenrico if always return true then what you expect else? Because from your code return true means it redirect to "Page2.html".